# Why? Cannot convert value of type 'JSONArray' to expected argument type 'DataToValidate'

Tags: swift, enums

Have this method call:

```swift
let result = try validate(JSONArray([true]), schema: schema)
```

here is the declaration:

```swift
public func validate(_ value: DataToValidate, schema: JSONObject) throws -> ValidationResult {
  return try validator(for: schema).validate(instance: value)
}

public enum DataToValidate {
    case object(JSONObject)
    case array(JSONArray)
    case string(String)
}
```

Why, what is wrong? enum can be `JSONArray`.

Comment: `validate(JSONArray([true])` -> `validate(.array(JSONArray([true]))`?

Comment: " enum can be JSONArray." No, it' s an enum with associated values. There is a `DataToValidate` case value, where there is a `JSONArray` associated value, but it's not a `JSONArray` value that is as the same time a `DataToValidate`. Read about them: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148